# Por que meu vetor está ordenado se estou ordenando em uma função (void) sem qualquer retorno?

Tags: array, memória, escopo-de-variáveis

Ao ordenar um vetor, em uma função do tipo **{void}** por que o vetor **(original)** na minha chamada da função é mostrado como ordenado já que o vetor que foi ordenado foi o vetor referente ao dos parâmetros formais da minha função **OrdenacaoBolha(int Vetor[], int TAM)**, pois o vetor ordenado devia estar fora do escopo de memória do vetor da minha **main**, já que ambos arranjos são variáveis locais, e devia ser exibido o vetor **Valores[]** sem está ordenado.

```
**void OrdenacaoBolha(int Vetor[], int TAM) {
    int aux;
    for(int i=0; i<TAM; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<TAM-1; j++) {
            if (Vetor[j]>Vetor[j+1]) {
                aux = Vetor[j];
                Vetor[j] = Vetor[j+1];
                Vetor[j+1] = aux;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(void) {
    int Valores[] = {14, 32, 1, 7, 3, 2, 0};
    int TAM = sizeof(Valores)/sizeof(int);
    OrdenacaoBolha(Valores, TAM);
    for(int i=0; i<7; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", Valores[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

arrays são containers onde cada espaço é um ponteiro para cada valor assim quando se coloca array em um parametro de array você acaba alterando os valores do original

Comment: então quer dizer que cada posição de um vetor na realidade é um ponteiro de forma implícita né, daí quando passo o argumento para a função e ela ordena os valores é atualizada o vetor original pelo fato de apontar para o da função. Então tecnicamente os arranjos (Unidimensionais, bidimensionais e tridimensionais) de uma forma geral são só ponteiros.

Comment: de uma maneira mais tecnica quando se referencia o array apenas pelo nome da variavel ele retorna o endereço do primeiro elemento do array, o array em si são apenas uma maneira de criar uma estrutura na memoria explicando de uma maneira mais facil de compreender: quando você colocou "Valores" como argumento da função ele retornou um endereço onde o primeiro valor 14 estava armazenado na memoria, por exemplo no endereço 38AD como todo o int tem 4 bytes, na função se colocado Vetor[1] ele vai somar 38AD + 4 e vai dar no endereço onde esta armazenado o segundo elemento do array na memoria

Answer (score 1):

Arrays em linguagem C são tratados como ponteiros. Isso significa que uma variável do tipo array "aponta" para o primeiro elemento do array. Nesse caso, quando passa um array por parâmetro está passando na verdade a "referência" para onde começa o array, e não uma cópia dele, portanto não importa se é a função que foi declarado ou em outra, se ele for alterado, a alteração é feita no array "original".

Não acho que seja o o problema no seu exemplo, apenas a dúvida, mas se fosse necessário manter o array original por alguma razão, precisaria fazer uma cópia dele, por exemplo declarando outro e passando cada valor de um array para o outro no `for` por exemplo, ou ainda usando o `memcopy`, assim:

```
int Valores2[7];
memcpy(Valores2, Valores, sizeof(Valores));
OrdenacaoBolha(Valores2, TAM);
```

Assim passa a referência para outro array, preservando o primeiro

Comment: Ricardo, então na minha segunda função trabalho nada mais, nada menos que apenas as referências de cada posição do meu vetor original sendo um ponteiro. Deve se por isso que se chama passagem por referência né?

Comment: sim exato, você passa a referência, o objeto é um só em memória :)